# Geth fast sync takes way too long

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten, testrpc-to-ropsten

I am syncing my local node with rospten test network with geth sync --fast, but it takes more than 24 hours, though 99% complete, i am not able to communicate with my token contract that was deployed in ropsten.

All the query like account balance,, symbol, totalsupply etc returns either null or zero in js console

Should i stop syncing?

Answer (score 0):

## Try parity for fast initial sync

If you're not interested in indexing anything in the past, parity can start up very quickly compared with geth.

A quick startup can be achieved with:

```
parity --no-ancient-blocks
```

Comment: geth completed sync in 24 hours. The size of data folder is considerably high and obvious to be increasing

Comment: Does Parity support something like Geth's fast mode? I mean, something that still allows retrieving transaction information from the RPC server.